# How to use single quotes in the label of a node using GraphViz in R?

Tags: r, graphviz, single-quotes

I am trying to label a node using GraphViz in R. I want to see the node labelled as `'ABC'` instead of simply `ABC`. This is what I did :

```
library( DiagrammeR ) 

DiagrammeR(diagram = "", type = "grViz")

#.....Using GraphViz.....

grViz("
          
digraph dot {

graph[layout = dot,
      rankdir = LR]

#....adding node statements....
node[shape = circle,
     style = filled,
     color = grey,
     label = ' 'ABC' ']

node[fillcolor = red]
'ABC'
}        

")
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
Error: syntax error in line 12 near '"'
```

Comment: try '\\'ABC\\''

Comment: if you can pass a variable, try this - `paste("'", "ABC", "'", sep = "")`

Comment: That won't be possible as GraphViz i.e. "grViz" do not accept use of double quotes within double quotes.